# Correct implementation of ref counting smart pointer

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers, copy-constructor

#### Intro:

We're trying to implement our own ref-counting smart pointer (something similar to `std::shared_ptr`). We already have reference counted interface class from which other classes can inherit. The interface delivers `grab()` and `drop()` methods which are incrementing and decrementing ref count accordingly. Tldr manual ref counting. What we want to do now is RAII-like wrapper over this which calls `grab()` while copying (copy ctor) and `drop()` in destructor.

#### Code

Here's [source code](https://github.com/Crisspl/IrrlichtBAW/blob/58529f5b6f1cb915fd56d22e048bf41b46e2e1b7/include/irr/core/IReferenceCounted.h#L184) to implementation of our smart pointer described in Intro section. Also necessary part of it is pasted below:

```
    //IReferenceCounted is the interface class defining grab() and drop() methods incrementing and decrementing ref count

    template<class I_REFERENCE_COUNTED>
    class smart_refctd_ptr
    {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<IReferenceCounted, I_REFERENCE_COUNTED>::value,"Wrong Base Class!");
            
            mutable I_REFERENCE_COUNTED* ptr; // since IReferenceCounted declares the refcount mutable atomic
            template<class U> friend class smart_refctd_ptr;
        public:
            constexpr smart_refctd_ptr() noexcept : ptr(nullptr) {}
            constexpr smart_refctd_ptr(std::nullptr_t) noexcept : ptr(nullptr) {}
            template<class U>
            explicit smart_refctd_ptr(U* _pointer) noexcept : ptr(_pointer)
            {
                if (_pointer)
                    _pointer->grab();
            }
            template<class U>
            explicit smart_refctd_ptr(U* _pointer, dont_grab_t t) noexcept : ptr(_pointer) {}
            template<class U>
            smart_refctd_ptr(const smart_refctd_ptr<U>& other) noexcept : smart_refctd_ptr(other.ptr) {}
            template<class U>
            smart_refctd_ptr(smart_refctd_ptr<U>&& other) noexcept : smart_refctd_ptr()
            {
                if (ptr) // should only happen if constexpr (is convertible)
                    ptr->drop();
                ptr = other.ptr;
                other.ptr = nullptr; // should only happen if constexpr (is convertible)
            }
            ~smart_refctd_ptr() noexcept
            {
                if (ptr)
                    ptr->drop();
            }

            template<class U>
            inline smart_refctd_ptr& operator=(U* _pointer) noexcept
            {
                if (_pointer)
                    _pointer->grab();
                if (ptr)
                    ptr->drop();
                ptr = _pointer;
                return *this;
            }
            template<class U>
            inline smart_refctd_ptr& operator=(const smart_refctd_ptr<U>& other) noexcept
            {
                return operator=(other.ptr);
            }
            template<class U>
            inline smart_refctd_ptr& operator=(smart_refctd_ptr<U>&& other) noexcept
            {
                if (ptr) // should only happen if constexpr (is convertible)
                    ptr->drop();
                ptr = other.ptr;
                other.ptr = nullptr; // should only happen if constexpr (is convertible)
                return *this;
            }

            inline I_REFERENCE_COUNTED* get() { return ptr; }
            inline const I_REFERENCE_COUNTED* get() const { return ptr; }

            inline I_REFERENCE_COUNTED* operator->() { return ptr; }
            inline const I_REFERENCE_COUNTED* operator->() const { return ptr; }

            inline I_REFERENCE_COUNTED& operator*() { return *ptr; }
            inline const I_REFERENCE_COUNTED& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

            inline I_REFERENCE_COUNTED& operator[](size_t idx) { return ptr[idx]; }
            inline const I_REFERENCE_COUNTED& operator[](size_t idx) const { return ptr[idx]; }


            inline explicit operator bool() const { return ptr; }
            inline bool operator!() const { return !ptr; }

            template<class U>
            inline bool operator==(const smart_refctd_ptr<U> &other) const { return ptr == other.ptr; }
            template<class U>
            inline bool operator!=(const smart_refctd_ptr<U> &other) const { return ptr != other.ptr; }

            template<class U>
            inline bool operator<(const smart_refctd_ptr<U> &other) const { return ptr < other.ptr; }
            template<class U>
            inline bool operator>(const smart_refctd_ptr<U>& other) const { return ptr > other.ptr; }
    };
```

#### The problem

As it turns out, it's not so easy as it looks because of, I think, copy elision. Copy constructor of our smart pointer is NOT called while making copy. I'm working in Visual Studio 2017 and it seems like there's even no assembly generated from copy constructor C++ code: i cannot put a breakpoint in there, nor see any asm generated for it.
Even for these 2 simple lines of C++ code...

```
    core::smart_refctd_ptr<IAsset> mesh_ptr(mesh);
    core::smart_refctd_ptr<IAsset> mesh_ptr2 = mesh_ptr;
```

...I'm getting this asm:

```
;    core::smart_refctd_ptr<IAsset> mesh_ptr(mesh);
 mov         rdx,qword ptr [mesh]  
 lea         rcx,[mesh_ptr]  
 call        irr::core::smart_refctd_ptr<irr::asset::IAsset>::smart_refctd_ptr<irr::asset::IAsset><irr::asset::SCPUMesh> (013F2A79B7h)  
 nop  
 ;   core::smart_refctd_ptr<IAsset> mesh_ptr2 = mesh_ptr;
 mov         rax,qword ptr [mesh_ptr]  
 mov         qword ptr [mesh_ptr2],rax
```

Copy constructor is not called at all. And so ref count is not incremented, but 2 destructors are called which obviously leads to bigger number of decrements than increments. This happens on **debug build with /Od flag** (didn't even try full optimizations on yet).
Since it's supposed to be very similar to `std::shared_ptr`, I looked up its implementation in my compiler (VS2017 as I mentioned above). However I can't really see any trick that would show me a solution. I tried - `std::shared_ptr` works fine (ref count is properly incremented on copy), but I don't know why. Why shared_ptr works and our `smart_refctd_ptr` doesn't?

Comment: Good question except... Links rot. Sometimes they're blocked by firewalls. You can't count on them for any important part of the question, and code's usually pretty darn important.

Comment: Please, include the necessary code into the question itself.

Comment: This is a neat question, but do you need to avoid copy elision? Sure, you may have had a copy, but if the source that's being returned is instantly destroyed, who cares? Refcount goes up for a couple cycles, then back down. When you call into a function, the refcount doesn't matter much because the caller still has a copy. This has me thinking you've hit something else and I need to click that link to fully understand the question.

Comment: You don't actually have a user defined copy constructor. A copy constructor is never a template.

Comment: If you need an intrusive smart pointer, you can use one from boost.

Comment: I added our smart pointer's source code to question.
@user4581301 The thing is that copy constructor is not executed BUT destructor is executed for original object and the copy and so the managed object is destroyed too early.

Comment: @n.m. that's probably the answer here (the copy constructor is implicit, not supplied by the template member function) - care to write it in the answer box?

Comment: Making non-templated copy constructor fixed the problem - ref count is now incremented properly. Same thing needed to be done with copy assignment operator. But I still don't understand the past behaviour. Why an instantiation of "templated copy ctor" wasn't called? I'll put it as an answer if I'll manage to reopen the question, but still an explanation would be appreciated. @n.m. am I correctly understanding that since what i called copy ctor was templated, there was no user-defined one thus the default copy ctor was invoked?

Comment: It is so because the standard says so. "A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was making non-template copy constructor. User-defined copy constructor must be non-template constructor as C++14 standard states at **12.8.2 [class.copy]**. Same thing needed to be done with move constructor, copy assignment operator and move assignment operator. So that copy constructor now looks like this:

```
            template<class U>
            void copy(const smart_refctd_ptr<U>& other) noexcept
            {
                if (other.ptr)
                    other.ptr->grab();
                ptr = other.ptr;
            }

            template<class U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U,I_REFERENCE_COUNTED>::value, int> = 0>
            smart_refctd_ptr(const smart_refctd_ptr<U>& other) noexcept
            {
                this->copy(other);
            }
            smart_refctd_ptr(const smart_refctd_ptr<I_REFERENCE_COUNTED>& other) noexcept
            {
                this->copy(other);
            }
```

Note that `std::enable_if_t<...,int> = 0` template parameter is most likely not needed.